# Calling function from another function

Tags: python

When I call func1 from func2, I get an error. Why is this occurring and how to access the returned dictionary d in func1 from func2?

> ```
> func1()
> NameError: name 'func1' is not defined
> ```

```
class ABC():

    def func1(self, a):
         d = {}
         ###do something with a
         ###return ending dictionary d
         return d

    def func2(self):
         ###Retrieve returned dictionary d from func1 and use
         func1()
         d['key'] = value
```

Comment: `class ABC:` parthensis are not needed here

Comment: `d = self.func1()` calling a method and setting returned value to `d` (although you could use a completely different name here, e.g. `result = self.func1()`)

Answer (score 2):

func1 and func2 are instance methods of ABC objects. You need to call them from the instance of such object.
In your case, one such instance is `self`, first parameter of both functions.
Thus, `self.func1()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `self.func1()` to call the function inside your class.